# Facebook Share button conflict with Facebook JSSDK. How to resolve?

Tags: facebook

I can't seem to get both scripts working. I am using the jssdk and fb.share to get facebook like box plus facebook share button. But they do not work together. Any idea why? How to fix this?

I have this in header:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

And this code in footer:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This is my Fb.share code:

```
    <div class="shr-fb">
        <a name="fb_share"></a>
        <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
```

They make conflict with each other and I do not know how to resolve this situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes sense.
The facebook share is deprecated and no longer supported, as you can read in the docs:

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

(reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/)

And:

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

(reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Instead, use the [Like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and you won't run into conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, you can still combine both Like and Share buttons together with FaceBook JSSDK Api and the html snippet for that is;

```html
<div class="fb-like" data-share="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

It will display both the Like and Share buttons functioning as required.